# How many ways can n married couples sit at a round table in such a way that there is one man between every two women and no man is seated next to wife

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, problem-solving, inclusion-exclusion

I was just attempting to do the following question:

How many ways can n married couples sit at a round table in such a way that there is one man between every two women and no man is seated next to his wife?

I immediately thought about the well known cyclic permutations formula, which says that if there are n distinct numbers in a circle, there are $(n-1)!$ distinct cyclic permutations of them. I thought that maybe we could use this for each of the two women and then for the man. Unfortunately, I tried it and I couldn't make it to work out. I then thought of the generalized inclusion exclusion principle, but I couldn't think of anything conclusive there either. I have been looking at it for a while now, could you please explain to me how it can be solved using the inclusion-exclusion principle? Moreover, if there exists a simple solution without it, could you please show me how it is solved like that as well? This problem is similar to the problemes des menages by E. Loucas. I have looked for it on the internet, however, I haven't managed to understand any of the solutions

Comment: See https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/menage/menage/menage.html

Comment: Thanks @AnginaSeng I'll look at it now and see if I understand it

Comment: Actually, @AnginaSeng I have just looked at it and it isn't the same question, thanks for the link though

Comment: Is https://oeis.org/A000179 what you want ?

Comment: @Michael: So far as I can see, it is the identical problem. Why do you think that it’s different? The **relaxed** ménage problem is different, but they use that only as a stepping stone to what appears to be your problem.

Comment: I had misunderstood my own question :). @BrianM.Scott, you're right, thank you very much. Have a good day

Comment: @Michael: You’re welcome!